# Clipping Mask Error in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a Visiting Card in Illustrator and have to fit the pic of a person in a visiting card Frame.
I am clipping his pic in the frame but it says the Can't clipping because the front part of the clipping must be an object or text or combination of both.

Plz Help me out on this problem.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error? Can you provide a screen shot of your document?

Comment: How on earth is this off topic? This fits in with 90% of the questions here.

Answer (score 2):

This error could be because your layers aren't adjacent to one another. One of the two senarios gives me that same error:

1. If the layer your mask shape isn't directly above the layer your object is on, this error pops up.
2. If the mask layer is below the intended object your masking, this error pops up also.

Check the order of your layers and try making the mask again.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closed path sitting on top of your image. Then select both objects and make your mask. I believe they also have to be either ungrouped objects or in the same group.